# Should an example from the Arabi manual compile?

Tags: texstudio, examples, persian

I tried to compile the figure 7.3 from the Arabi user-guide.pdf version 1.1 from december 16, 2006. It didnot compile instantly I had to make changes to the copy from the pdf. The problem were the braces. Is this the intended behavior? I doubt it. Is there a newer version?

This should be in "code" but the arabic part cannot be added with four spaces (at least I can not do it). My addition to the text are the braces at the end. They were needed for compilation

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[LFE,LAE,OT1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[farsi,english,arabic]{babel}

\Novocalize

\begin{document}

%\selectlanguage{arabic} %the default in this case

\title{%

%شمس النهار

}

\author{توفيق الحكيم}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter {      }توفيق الحكيم

الإسكندرية - \I{ في هذا الشهر، يحتفل العالم العربي بالذكرى المئوية 
لمولد     توفيق الحكيم ( { 1898
القاهرة ). \I{1987}
وقد حظي الحكيم بمكانة متميزة على خريطة تطور الكتابة الإبداعية العربية؛ فهو كاتب واحدة من أولى
وهو - أيضا - كاتب أول مسرحية عربية ناضجة بمعايير النقد ،(\I{ الروايات العربية: عودة الروح ({ 1933
وقبلها، كان الحكيم قد كتب أولى مسرحياته في سن مبكرة بعنوان الضيف .(\I{ الحديث: أهل الكهف ({ 1933
ضد الاحتلال البريطاني. \I{ الثقيل ، وذلك إبان ثورة { 1919
وصف الحكيم بأنه مؤسس المسرح المصري المعاصر ، وبأنه من جعل المسرح في العالم العربي جنسا أدبيا
مرموقا . وقد اتسمت لغة أعماله المسرحية باليسر والمرونة، وحرص على أن يبرز فيها روح

...}}}}}}}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem in this line `\chapter {      }توفيق الحكيم`. Place the arabic words inside the curly brackets not out of them as this `\chapter {توفيق الحكيم}`. Also, don't leave empty spaces in the title

```
\title{%
%شمس النهار
}
```